# Django time displays One Hour ahead after launching site

Tags: django, time

I have a site I have just launched on www.pythonanywhere.com but if I post something, instead of to say `1 minute ago` it says `1 hour ago`. Our timezone is *GMT+1*

This is my **settings.py**:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the post to show 1 minute ago, you need to set the user's timezone to GMT+1 using `activate()`. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/timezones/#default-time-zone-and-current-time-zone).